Does Navier-Stokes formulation change over timeline?
In this article write:
"the equation was rediscovered or re-derived at least four times, by Cauchy in 1823, by Poisson in 1829, by Saint-Venant in 1837, and by Stokes in 1845"
"To Navier’s disappointment, his equation worked well only for slow, regular motions. This was enough for pendulums and capillary tubes, but was nearly worthless for hydraulics."
What mean equation was re-derived many times, that means that end up with new formulation each year? Or equation is always the same, just her proof is different?
If equation formulation is all these years the same, why for Navier 1822 formulation works only for slow motions, does Navier-Stokes formulation change over timeline?
Is below formulation from Navier 1822 or from Stokes 1845?


Navier or Stokes surely did not write them with $\nabla$, which was only introduced by Hamilton in 1853 and did not gain currency until late 19th century.

Bistafa "On the development of the Navier-Stokes equation by Navier" (2018)
